# How to dynamically update scatter chart series with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a worksheet with about 30 charts I want to update dynamically with a VBA macro. I have some issues in handling the series, but I can't find out what's wrong.

The code should run through several charts (only 3 in the following code), clear old contents, and add 6 new series with data taken from the spreadsheet. On the contrary, it doesn't delete the old series and, at each run, adds them again with a new one, then quits with a "Parameter not valid" error on line 22. I have been struggling on this for a couple of weeks now, and the most frustrating part is that the code is basically a copy+paste from another project, which works fine.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub Refresh_NB_Graphs()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim vi As Integer
    Dim s As Object
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim seriesIndex As Integer
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim yRange As Range

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    'Graph fetching and update cycle
    For vi = 1 To 3
        Set chtObj = Sh_NBGain.ChartObjects("Ch_Gain_Vs" & CStr(vi))
        Set cht = chtObj.Chart
        ' Adding or removing this section makes no difference -------
        For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
            s.Delete
        Next s
        ' -----------------------------------------------------------
        cht.ChartArea.ClearContents
        'Format Font Type and Size
        cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers                                   ' scatter plot
        cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
        cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
        cht.HasTitle = False      ' No chart title
        ' Add series: data origin in Sh_NBGainProcess
        seriesIndex = 0
        For j = 0 To 5
                seriesIndex = seriesIndex + 1
                cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
1               cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).Name = CStr(Sh_Vars.Range("A8").Offset(j, 0).Value)
                Set xRange = Sh_NBGainProcess.Range("C42:C1642").Offset(1600 * (vi - 1), 20 * j)
                Set yRange = Sh_NBGainProcess.Range("D42:D1642").Offset(1600 * (vi - 1), 20 * j)
10              cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).XValues = "='" & Sh_NBGainProcess.Name & "'!" & xRange.Address
20              cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).Values = "='" & Sh_NBGainProcess.Name & "'!" & yRange.Address
22              With cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex)
23                  Debug.Print seriesIndex
30                  .Format.Line.Weight = 2.25
40                  .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
50                  .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ECOPalette(j)    ' Array with defined colors
60                  .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
                End With
        Next j

        '.....................

     Next vi
End Sub
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: as for the line 22 issue, it'd seem you're using an invalid index for `SeriesCollection`: place a pointbreak at that line and query both `seriesIndex` and `cht.SeriesCollection.Count` via Immediate Window

Comment: cht.SeriesCollection.Count returns an "object doesn't support this property or method" error. Odd.

Comment: What's the value of `seriesIndex` returned by immediate window? Does it match your expectations? Once back in your code does Intellisense show you `Count` in the list after you type a dot after `cht.SeriesCollection`?

Comment: Yes. seriesIndex value is correct.

Comment: and what about the last question of mine?

Comment: Sorry. No, Intellisense doesn't provide any suggestion after cht.SeriesCollection.

Comment: no Intellisense at all? I mean you can't have it anywhere in your code?

Comment: Intellisense works properly, except for cht.SeriesCollection.* or ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.*, which show no hint.

Comment: with same point break as already discussed, query immediate window for `?Typename(cht)` and `?Typename(cht.SeriesCollection(1))`

Comment: ?Typename(cht) returns Chart. Both ?Typename(cht.SeriesCollection(1)) and ?Typename(cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex)) return Series.

Comment: try `Dim s As Series` ,`Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex)` and then `With s …. End With`

Comment: I think I found where the issue was, see answer below. I still don't understand why it didn't work...
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. And I don't understand why the solution is working, too. Have you tried with my last suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't work.

Comment: What error in what line? I know it's over, but just in case we should be interested in finding the "right" way...

Comment: I had to update my answer. After a few good tests, it started again to give an error in line 22. I think the problem was in the use of `cht.SeriesCollection(seriesIndex)`, but still I don't get why, since the value of the variable was correct throughout execution.

Comment: first off, if your answer isn't valid (yet) remove the mark, not to disguise other readers

Answer (score 0):

Had to rework the code a bit, but now it's fine:

```
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim s As Series
    Dim vi As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim yRange As Range

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    'Graph fetching and update cycle
    For vi = 1 To 3
        ' Gain charts (Vs 1 to 3) ***********************************************************************************************************
        Set cht = Sh_NBGain.ChartObjects("Ch_Gain_Vs" & CStr(vi)).Chart
        ' Clear existing data
        For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
            s.Delete
        Next s
        cht.ChartArea.ClearContents
        cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers                                   ' scatter plot

        ' Add series: data origin in Sh_NBGainProcess
        For j = 0 To 5
            If Not Sh_NBGainProcess.Range("C42").Offset(1601 * (vi - 1), 20 * j).Value = "" Then
10              Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
40              s.Name = CStr(Sh_Vars.Range("A8").Offset(j, 0).Value)
50              Set xRange = Sh_NBGainProcess.Range("C42:C1642").Offset(1601 * (vi - 1), 20 * j)
60              Set yRange = Sh_NBGainProcess.Range("D42:D1642").Offset(1601 * (vi - 1), 20 * j)
90               s.XValues = "='" & Sh_NBGainProcess.Name & "'!" & xRange.Address
100              s.Values = "='" & Sh_NBGainProcess.Name & "'!" & yRange.Address
110              With s
130                  .Format.Line.Weight = 2.25
140                  .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
150                  .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ECOPalette(j)
160                  .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
                End With
            End If
        Next j
```

I think that the main issue was due to the use of the series collection indexing, which was somehow misbehaving (I still don't understand why). By referring directly to the series object when created, with Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries, things go fine.